# Swift 5: How to make a Set containing Class Types (for NSXPCInterface)

Tags: swift, hashable

In [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsxpcinterface/1415555-setclasses) of `NSXPCInterface.setClasses(_:for:argumentIndex:ofReply:)`, for Swift, the first parameter is described as:

*An NSSet containing Class objects —for example, [MyObject class]*.

Hmmm, it looks as though someone neglected to update this from Objective-C to Swift.  For Swift I presume it should be something like

*A Set containing Class Types*

(Someone please correct my wording.)  But **how do you make a Set containing Class Types?**  The compiler will not allow me to declare a `Set` whose member types are not do not conform to `Hashable`.  This makes sense because hashes are needed to maintain uniqueness among members.  But Class Types in Swift do not seem to be hashable.  Try this in any Swift file, or a playground…

```
class Foo {}
let mySet: Set<AnyHashable>
mySet.insert(Foo)
```

The compiler complains:

*Argument type 'Foo.Type' does not conform to expected type 'Hashable'*

Or, more broadly, does anyone know how to use `NSXPCInterface.setClasses(_:for:argumentIndex:ofReply:)` in Swift 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classes you pass need to be @objc classes (and subclasses of NSObject). You'll put them into an NSSet, and then cast that to Set:

```
let classSet = NSSet(object: Foo.self) as! Set<AnyHashable>
```

This is almost certainly a bug in NSXPCInterface (it needs some kind of "refine for Swift" or possibly a shim), and I suggest opening a defect at bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Your workaround is perfect, Rob.  I have filed Apple Bug 50514123.

Answer (score 1):

As of Swift v5.6 (perhaps earlier), you can create the set without casting:

```
let classSet = NSSet().adding(Foo.self)
```

This is because `adding()` is declared like this:

```
open func adding(_ anObject: Any) -> Set<AnyHashable>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple syntax to get a `Set<AnyHashable>` out of arbitrary types might be:

```
let classSet = [Foo.self] as NSSet as Set
```

No force cast needed and works well with NSXPCInterface.